# Heroku not using assets file for foundation icons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm using this gem, foundation-icons-sass-rails, installed according to their instructions.
https://github.com/zaiste/foundation-icons-sass-rails

I'm deploying to Heroku.

Everything is working fine, except the foundation icons do not work.

heroku logs reports "no route matches [GET] "/assets/foundation-icons.svg"

config/development.rb:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf)
```

config/production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

application.css.scss says:

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require foundation_and_overrides

 */

 @import 'foundation-icons';
```

I did rake assets:precompile and added to the repo before i pushed to Heroku

I see the file "foundation-icons-a2343234dblahblahblah.svg" in public/assets

Why is Heroku not finding it? Shouldn't it be looking for the fingerprinted file in public/assets, not the plain "/assets/foundation-icons.svg"

EDIT:

looking at heroku's docs, i ran the heroku rails console
and then did a puts helper.asset_path("foundation-icons.css")  and it responds that its just looking for the plain unfingerprinted file.  how do i tell my app that it needs to look for the fingerprinted version

Comment: In reference to your `edit`, Rails will only reference the fingerprinted file when in production mode. In development mode, it will just use the "native" file

Comment: Hey Chris to you find the solution to your problem? I have the same issue and other posts solutions haven't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see [this post in the project's GitHub issues section](https://github.com/zaiste/foundation-icons-sass-rails/issues/11)? It's a workaround, but:

> **aardvarkk commented on May 21**
>
> I was able to fix this without the figaro gem. I added the following:
>
> > `config.relative_url_root = "/mysuburi"`
>
> to the file `config/environments/production.rb`. Everything now works as expected. This is in > Rails v3.2.18.

Otherwise, I would open a new issue there.

Comment: looks like that just makes all my assets not found by affixing /appname to the front.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I would just make an issue there then as it's specific to their project.

Answer (score 0):

**Fonts**

This might not help directly, but you have to appreciate that when you reference fonts & other external dependencies in Rails' production asset pipeline, you'll have to use one of the [preprocessors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing) to reference *dynamic* paths

As you've pointed out, Rails will naturally [fingerprint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) the files it compiles in the asset piepline as follows:

> Fingerprinting is a technique that makes the name of a file dependent
>   on the contents of the file. When the file contents change, the
>   filename is also changed. For content that is static or infrequently
>   changed, this provides an easy way to tell whether two versions of a
>   file are identical, even across different servers or deployment dates.

This means that if you're calling the fonts, or images for that matter, from the CSS, you won't be able to use the default `url` statement:

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
body {
   background: url("your/background.png"); /* This won't work in production because of fingerprinting */
}
```

--

**Preprocessing**

Looks like you're using this already, so perhaps this won't help

But when you use a [preprocessor (SCSS / SASS)](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html) in Rails' asset pipeline, you will be able to use the Rails [asset_path helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-asset_path):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.sass
body
   background: asset_url("your/background.png")
```

In regards to using fonts, we've set it up as follows:

```
#app/assets/fonts/fonts.css.sass
@font-face
    font:
        family: 'Ionicons'
        weight: normal
        style: normal
    src: asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.eot?v=1.4.1')
    src: asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.eot?v=1.4.1#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.ttf?v=1.4.1') format('truetype'), asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.woff?v=1.4.1') format('woff'), asset_url('layout/fonts/IonIcons/ionicons.svg?v=1.4.1#Ionicons') format('svg')
```

I appreciate this does not help the issue with your gem. However, you need to make sure you have the correct urls set up for your assets, as per our code above. This will reference the fingerprinted asset files, regardless of what they're called :)